# Optimal way to survey a road

Tags: reference-request, optimization, computational-geometry

There is a road (a planar curve) of length 1. A treasure is placed in a random spot on the road. The treasure location is a uniform random variable, so that the probability to find the treasure in an interval of the road is equal to the interval length. Our goal is to find the treasure in the shortest expected time.

We have a helicopter that can survey the road and detect the treasure when it is directly below it. The helicopter can fly to any point in the road, but cannot survey the entire road at once because it has to go back to its fuelling base once every hour. Our goal is to divide the road to intervals, such that each interval can be covered in one hour, and the expected time until we find the treasure and return to the base is minimized.

An example is illustrated below:

[image]

Here, AE is the entire road. The probability of finding the treasure in AC is 1/2 (since its length is 1/2 the total road length), and the same is true for CE.  Suppose the helicopter can cover the interval AC in one hour (e.g, it takes one hour to fly from the Base to A, then to C, then back to the Base). Similarly, it can cover the interval CE in one hour. Then, the expected time of finding the treasure in the given schedule is:

$$E[T] = 1/2 \cdot 1 + 1/2 \cdot 2 = 1.5$$

This simple schedule is not necessarily optimal. It may be possible (depending on geometry) to divide the road to 3 segments, like this:

[image]

If the helicopter can cover each of the three intervals in at most one hour, and it surveys them in the order: BD, AB, DE, then the expected time is:

$$E[T] = 6/8 \cdot 1 + 1/8 \cdot 2 + 1/8 \cdot 3 = 11/8 = 1.375$$

In general, given a division of the road to $T$ intervals, each of which can be covered in an hour, the expected time is:

$$E[T] = \sum_{t=1}^T t\cdot Length_t $$

This expression indicates that the minimum expected time is attained when we survey the intervals in decreasing order of their length. However, this is minimal only *given the division to intervals*; it does not tell us what is the optimal way to divide the road to intervals.

So my questions are:

A. What is an algorithm for finding an optimal division of the road to intervals?

Suppose the input is given as an oracle that, given a point $x$ on the road, tells us $l(x)$ - the maximum length that can be surveyed in 1 hour, starting at $x$. Assume that $l(x)$ is a continuous monotonically increasing function of $x$.

B. Suppose we divide the road to the smallest possible number of intervals, like the AC-CE example above, and survey them in decreasing order of length. This is not optimal, but apparently it is a good heuristic. What is its approximation factor?

Comment: 1. The expected time for the first example is probably less than $1.5$ in practice, since presumably if the helicopter finds the treasure, it won't continue on its original flight plan -- it'll immediately head back to base.  Do you want us to ignore this and just solve the math problem?  2. What assumptions can we make about the oracle?  Is it continuous?  Is it monotone, or perhaps has only a single maxima?

Comment: @D.W. 1. Yes, for simplicity let's assume that the helicopter always works in whole hours.  2. We can assume that distances are continuous  (i.e, there are no impassable obstacles in the air) and monotone. I do not understand what you mean by "single maxima"?

Comment: As $x$ sweeps from $A$ to $E$, I would expect that it would increase until approximately the place where you hit point $C$, then it will decrease (because $C$ is closer to the base than $A$ or $E$ are).

Comment: @D.W. I see. Then we do not make such assumption, since the road can be curved.

Comment: "Assume that $l(x)$ is a continuous monotonically increasing function of $x$" contradicts "There is a road (a planar curve) of length 1" unless $f(x)$ is everywhere zero: If there is any $0 < x < 1$ such that $f(x) = \epsilon > 0$, then either $1 - \epsilon > x$, in which case $1-\epsilon/2 > 1-\epsilon > x$ implying $f(1-\epsilon/2) \ge \epsilon$ due to monotonicity, or $1 - \epsilon \le x$, in which case $\epsilon \ge x + 1 > 1$.  In both cases, the road extends past position 1.